# Knockout computer function cannot be evaluated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Please check my plunkr here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/pwKohFTmLPW1BKNwHxWR?p=preview

I have a simple computer function:

```
self.SubscribersOrEmails = ko.computed(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    if (self.Emails != null && self.Subscribers != null) {
        counter = self.Emails().length + self.Subscribers().length;
    }
    console.log("counter: " + counter);
    return counter;
}, self);
```

When I get to use it like this:
`self.SubscribersOrEmails()` then I get the error that `'SubscribersOrEmails is not a function'`
but when I do `console.log(self.SubscribersOrEmails)` then it prints out a function. So it IS a function.
How do I use it then? I want it to return an integer. Currently it returns a function, but I am not allowed to evaluate it.

Any idea what is going on with it?

### UPDATE

Some people have been seeing an old version of the plunkr for some bizarre reason.

I can now see that it's a declaration order issue.
If I do this:

```
self.SubscribersOrEmails = ko.computed(function() {
              var counter = 0;
                if (self.Emails != null && self.Subscribers != null) {
                    counter = self.Emails().length + self.Subscribers().length;
                }
            console.log("counter: " + counter);
            return counter;
        }, self); 

 self.Subscribers = ko.observableArray().extend({ required: { onlyIf: function () { console.log(self.SubscribersOrEmails()); return self.SubscribersOrEmails === 0}, params: 'Subscribers', message: "Please either select a user or type email address(es)" } })
 self.Emails = ko.observableArray().extend({ required: { onlyIf: function () { return self.SubscribersOrEmails == 0 }, params: 'Emails' } })
```

Then the function works but Emails and Subscribers is always zero because they don't exist when they are read.

If I do the opposite then the function doesn't exist.

So all possible order declarations cause problems :(

Comment: This is because your order of declaration. In the `extend` method, you are referring to a method that hasn't been declared yet. You can fix this by extending those observables after declaring that computed property.

Comment: I can't do that because then Emails() and Subscribers() will not exist!
This is catch 22.. Either the method won't exist, or the observableArrays won't exist. There is no correct order of declaration with this. What next?

Comment: You can extend the observables after declaring them. So, first, you declare `Emails` and `Subscribers`, something like `self.Email = ko.observableArray();` then you declare your computed. Now that all the properties exist, extend your observable arrays, `self.Email.extend(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your order of declaration. In the extend method, you are referring to a method that hasn't been declared yet. You can fix this by extending those observables after declaring that computed property.

```
self.Subscribers = ko.observableArray();
self.Emails = ko.observableArray();
self.SubscribersOrEmails = ko.computed(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    if (self.Emails != null && self.Subscribers != null) {
        counter = self.Emails().length + self.Subscribers().length;
    }
    console.log("counter: " + counter);
    return counter;
}, self); 

self.Subscribers.extend({ required: { onlyIf: function () { return self.SubscribersOrEmails == 0 }, params: 'Subscribers', message: "Please either select a user or type email address(es)" } })
self.Emails.extend({ required: { onlyIf: function () { return self.SubscribersOrEmails == 0 }, params: 'Emails' } })
```

Answer (score 1):

just added this line to `Emails` and `Subscribers`

```
onlyIf: function() {
    return self.SubscribersOrEmails && self.SubscribersOrEmails() === 0;
}
```

check this updated working [**Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ajrv9nMVBr1Ne0vryt9i?p=preview)

Comment: No you guys, why do you see an old version? Please try refreshing your screen. I pressed "Freeze" now, not sure what it does but maybe it'll help update it

Comment: Yes your plunkr doesn't work. It fixed a problem I had already fixed myself. Try my new plunkr

Comment: You are right. This works as well. Thanks for that. I will still keep Carrie's answer as the accepted one because it solved that mystery about the declaration order